# Does algebraic independence of logarithms conjecture imply L-W?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Assume that algebraic independence of logarithms conjecture is true: Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be algebraic numbers such that $\log(a_1),\cdots,\log(a_n)$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independant. Then, $\log(a_1),\cdots,\log(a_n)$ are algebraically independant.

Does it imply that Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is true:
Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be algebraic numbers that are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independant. Then, $e^{a_1},\cdots,e^{a_n}$ are algebraically independant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is a theorem, everything true or false implies it. Do you mean to ask if there is a particularly short proof for Lindemann-Weierstrass from the conjecture in question?